# dvips not thread-safe

Tags: dvips

Running `dvips -z` produces two temporary files `head.tmp` and `body.tmp`.
So when I run `dvips` on different files concurrently in the same dir, sometimes the different `head.tmp` or `body.tmp` "overlap" (AFAICT).

Is there any way to change the name of these auxiliary files?

A MWE can be as follows (here I'm running dvips multiple times on the same file, but I think the problem is the same).
If you run it, sometimes you end up with errors such as
`dvips: ! Could not find header file body.tmp.`.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF > mwe.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
EOF

latex mwe

dvips -z mwe -o & \
    dvips -z mwe -o & \
    dvips -z mwe -o & \
    dvips -z mwe -o &
```